# How do I make a UINavigationBar respond to taps?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a tableViewController/navController setup. I want to tap on the navbar of the navController to force the tableView back to the top row. I can see that the navbar is a UIView subclass, but I am unclear if I need to subclass it and implement the touch sequence methods.

I've build the view hierarchy in IB so I am reluctant to build it all programmatically just to enable tapping of the navbar.

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Are you aware of the built-in functionality that does scroll-to-top when you touch the status bar? http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollsToTop

Comment: Hah! Is was working all the time, I just never thought to tap the status bar. I was futility tapping the navbar. Cool. Cool. Cool!

 Cheers.

Comment: Sixten Otto. I'm happy to give you the answer on this one. Just resubmit your reply as an answer rather then a comment. Cheers.

Comment: Mark it as answered @dugla; click the checkmark under his vote count to the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OS already defines the "tap on the status bar" gesture to mean "scroll to the top of the current view." `UIScrollView` has a property [`scrollsToTop`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollsToTop) that controls this behavior, and `UITableView` inherits it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change what subclass any item is in interface builder.  Just create your subclass, add it to your XCode project, and then you'll be able to enter it in as the class instead of the normal value.

For a simple example on how to override a class look [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5440-silent-uipickerview.html).